# How to get the data of type stream from web service

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, web-services, nsinputstream

I want to read the stream data from server with corresponding URLs, currently i am trying with NSInputStream for reading the data , But i am getting the error "Error 2 The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory". The web developer receiving the data in bytes formate then he converted that data to Stream like MemoryStream(byteData)[NOTE:Web services are written in .net] and have returned the same to me. **What is the way to read such a kind of data**, *I tried the AISHTTPRequest got the file of size 0 bytes, I tried the NSURLConnction again i got file of size 0 bytes, Now I am using the NSInputStream and I am getting the ERROR mentioned at the starting*. Here is my code for NSInputStream,

***Please guide me whether we can read this kind of data is iOS as a front end, If Yes 
Then guide for the way that how should i interact with this kind of data. 
IF the NSInputStream is the intended way to interact with then whats the problem in my code written below.***

```
- (void)setUpStreamForFile {

    NSString *urlStr = @"http://192.168.1.201/example/example.svc/example?parameter={\"DCU_DocId\":\"05e24018-b728-4ec8-9848-d6cae02bec95\"}";

    // iStream is NSInputStream instance variable
    iStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:urlStr];
    [iStream setProperty:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id) kCFBooleanFalse,    kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain, nil ] forKey:(NSString *) kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings];
    [iStream setDelegate:self];
    [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                       forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [iStream open];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    int bytesRead=0;

    switch(eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        {
            if(!_data) {

            }
            uint8_t buf[20480];
            unsigned int len = 0;
            len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buf maxLength:20480];
            if(len) {
                [_data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
                // bytesRead is an instance variable of type NSNumber.
                //[bytesRead setIntValue:[bytesRead intValue]+len];
                bytesRead = bytesRead +len;
                NSLog(@"bytesRead:%d",bytesRead);
            }

            else {
                NSLog(@"no buffer!");
            }

            break;
        }
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
        {
            [stream close];
            [stream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                              forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            stream = nil; // stream is ivar, so reinit it
            break;
        }
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        {
            NSError *theError = [stream streamError];
            UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %i: %@",[theError code], [theError localizedDescription]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            NSLog(@"Error %i %@",[theError code], [theError localizedDescription]);
            [theAlert show];

            [stream close];

            break;
        }
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        {
            NSLog(@"EventOpen");
        }
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        {
             NSLog(@"EventHasSpac");
        }
        case NSStreamEventNone:
        {
            NSLog(@"EventNone");
        }
       }
}
```

Comment: I suggest using JSON for communications between iOS and .Net Web services. This will force .Net developer to serialize byte stream in JSON format readable in iOS app, like base64

Answer (score 5):

Its all using the NSUrlConnection to download the streamed data. It get solved.